# Case comments access level issues

Tags: case

I have created a custom profile in our sandbox, I would like to provide access only to Case object for this profile and no access for case comments.. In the profile object settings, for CASE, i do not see  a way to disable the access to case comments.. Under App permissions, the only option is to un check the "Edit Comments" privilege..I did that..
Even though I removed case comment from the page layout, but if a user logs in with this custom profile and do a global search, they are still are seeing the search results from case comments..

My intent is for my custom profile users, when someone does a global search, it should not return results from the case comments.

Is there any way to achieve this.. Please throw some light on this...Thanks